# How to solve a contour integral?

Tags: integration, contour-integration

I am trying to solve the contour integral

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{e^{t}}{t(2at+x^2)}{\rm{exp}}\left(\frac{ax^2}{2(2at+x^2)}\right)\,{\rm d}t
$$

where the path of integration $C$ starts at $-\infty-i0$ on the
real axis, goes to $-\varepsilon-i0$, circles the origin in the
counterclockwise direction with radius $\varepsilon$ to the point
$-\varepsilon+i0$ and returns to the point $-\infty+i0$ (I got
such path from Hankel's contour integral of reciprocal Gamma
function $1/\Gamma(z)$).

I concluded that a given function
$$\frac{e^{t}}{t(2at+x^2)}{\rm{exp}}\left(\frac{ax^2}{2(2at+x^2)}\right)$$
has two poles: First one is $t=0$ and I also calculated the
residual in that pole and it is equal to $\frac{e^{a/2}}{x^2}$;
second one is at $t=-\frac{x^2}{2a}$ and I am not sure is it a
pole of first or second order (because of the denominator of
exponential part). Also, when I computed residual at such pole (I
tried to compute residuals in both cases -when it is a pole of the
first kind and also the second kind) in each case I got $+\infty$
and I do not know what that means.

Please help me with some ideas to calculate such integral. Thank you in advance!

Comment: the pole at $t = -x^2/(2a)$ is an essential singularity, so you'll have to express the whole function as a Laurent series $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_k (t-x^2/(2a))^k$ around that point (the residue being $c_{-1}$)

Comment: dear user1952009 thank you very much. please can you give me just a little bit detailed hint what to do or maybe where to find such examples? tnx :)

Comment: the Laurent series for $e^{1/z}$ around $z=0$ is straightforward... and a Laurent series multiplied by a power series (or a Laurent series) is again a Laurent series (at least formally, there is still the problem of the region of convergence, but here everything works fine)

Comment: Because the integrand is singlevalued u can shrink ur contour into two points, one around $t=0$ and one around $t=-x^2/(2a)$

Comment: thank you... I'm stuck with the idea of expressing the whole function as a Laurent series around $t=-x^2/(2a)$ but I will keep trying :)

Comment: I derived a Laurent series, exactly I got a product of three such series and I don't know what to do next... so please if you can find time to look at a new question "Laurent series of a function around t=0" -I post it because I couldn't copy my calculations here (it was too big). Thank you in advance.